# Incorrect TIMESTAMP value Laravel DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, scheduler

I have a laravel project set up on localhost where I created a command in the scheduler which is the following:

`DB::table('relic')->where('created_at', '<', 'NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH')->delete();`

I tested running the scheduler command through artisan
and I get this output: 
`` Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1525 Incorrect TIMESTAMP value: 'NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH' (SQL: delete from `relic` where `created_at` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ``

I tested the commands
`SELECT * FROM relic WHERE created_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;`
and
`SELECT * FROM relic WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;`

in mysql itself and both worked properly. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library is included with Laravel, and it is the "standard" way to deal with dates and times. You can write your query as follows:

```
DB::table('relic')
  ->where('created_at', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())
  ->delete();
```

If you would like to use your syntax you can do so with a [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) statement like so:

```
DB::table('relic')
  ->whereRaw('created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH')
  ->delete();
```